# How to ground a fixture on a conduit?

Tags: electrical, ground

I am replacing a line-voltage path light that screws onto the top of a 1/2" metal conduit. I am pulling new wire through the conduit. Since the conduit is metal, I expect to use it as a ground path. However, I don't see how I make a connection from a ground wire in the light fixture to the conduit. I am sort of imagining some sort of clip that would surround the wires and make contact with the conduit to which the fixture wire could be attached, but I've never seen same. Or, for a metal fixture, may I assume that the ground wire need not be connected if the fixture is threaded onto metal?

Answer (score 2):

First, check all the directions that came with the fixture to see if they have special instructions on how to install it. You'll have to verify that the conduit is a continuous run eventually entering the main panel and insure it's grounded. Then, screwing the metal fixture to the conduit will ground it. Check to see how the fixture ground wire is connected to the fixture, you can probably remove the wire if it's just screwed into the fixture. Depending on the fixture, the instructions might call for you to run a ground wire with your other wires.